# On the intersection of index 2 subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two *distinct* index $2$ subgroups of a finite group $G$.
We can deduce several properties about the intersection $H_1 \cap H_2$:

1. $H_1$ and $H_2$ are normal subgroups of $G$. Then  $H_1 \cap H_2$ is also a normal subgroup of $G$.
2. $|G:H_1 \cap H_2| \le |G:H_1| \cdot |G:H_2|$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/170918/84284)), so $|G:H_1 \cap H_2| = 4$.
3. It follows that $G/(H_1 \cap H_2) \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$.

Let $(N \subset M)$ be an irreducible finite index inclusion of hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ factors.
Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be two *distinct* intermediate subfactors  $N \subset K_i \subset  M$, such that $|M:K_i| = 2$.

*Question*: What can be extended from the properties above?  More precisely:

1. $K_1$ and $K_2$ are depth $2$ subfactors. Is $K_1 \cap K_2$ also of depth $2$?
2. Is it true that $|M:K_1 \cap K_2| \le |M:K_1| \cdot |M:K_2|$, and so that  $|M:K_1 \cap K_2| = 4$?
3. Is it true that $M = (K_1 \cap K_2) \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$?

---

**Edit:** It is false in general for 2. and 3. (see answer). So now only 1. is asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false in general for 2. and 3.

Let $R$ be the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ factor, and take the symmetric group $S_3$ acting outerly on $R$.
Now take the subfactor $(R^{S_3} \subset R)$. Take the intermediate $K_1= R^{\langle (1,2) \rangle}$ and  $K_2=R^{\langle (1,3) \rangle}$.
Then $|R:K_i| = 2$, but by Galois correspondence $R^{\langle (1,2) \rangle} \cap R^{\langle (1,3) \rangle} = R^{\langle (1,2),(1,3) \rangle} = R^{S_3} $.
It follows that $|R: R^{\langle (1,2) \rangle} \cap R^{\langle (1,3) \rangle}| = 6 > 4 $. So 2. and 3. are false in general.

The point 1. is true for any finite group-subgroup subfactor $(R^G \subset R^H)$ because if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two distinct intermediate subgroups $H \subset H_i \subset G$, such that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $H_i$, then $H$ is also a normal subgroup of $\langle H_1, H_2 \rangle$

The point 1. is true in general, see the last paragraph of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/249776/34538) of Zhengwei.
In the same answer, Zhengwei shows what are the true statements for 2. and 3.
2.  $|M:K_1 \cap K_2| = 2n$
3.  $(K_1 \cap K_2)  = M^{D_{2n}}$ with $D_{2n}$ the [dihedral group](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupe_di%C3%A9dral) of order $2n$, because any finite quotient of the group $\mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/2$ admits the presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^2, b^2, (ab)^n \rangle$.